# Execute raw query in migration - Sequelize 3.30

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to execute a raw query in my migrations `up` and `down` functions.

When I try to do: `Sequelize.query`, it says `ERROR: Sequelize.query is not a function`.

This is my migration skeleton file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {

  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize, migration) => {
     return Sequelize.query(...);   //ERROR: Sequelize.query is not a Function
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
     return Sequelize.query(...);  //ERROR: Sequelize.query is not a Function
  }

};
```

Comment: `Sequelize` =>  is this variable `require('sequelize')`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `query()` method you are looking for is an instance rather than class method. It exists on `Sequelize` **instances**, not on the class itself.

In migrations, you can access the instance through the provided `queryInterface` object as `queryInterface.sequelize`.

So your migration should look like:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {

  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize, migration) => {
     return queryInterface.sequelize.query(...);
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
     return queryInterface.sequelize.query(...);
  }

};
```