# Sequelize bulk insert error with polygon column

Tags: javascript, mariadb, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have the following model with a column of type polygon

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('p_zones', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      points: {
        type: Sequelize.GEOMETRY('POLYGON')
      },
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('ZonePoints');
  }
};
```

And when I try to seed using sequelize-cli with the command `npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all`

```
const polygon = {
      type: 'Polygon',
      coordinates: [
        [
          [10, 10],
          [20, 10],
          [20, 20],
          [10, 20],
          [10, 10],
        ],
      ],
    };
 const data = [{ points: polygon }];
 await queryInterface.bulkInsert('p_zones', data);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid value {
  type: 'Polygon',
  coordinates: [ [ [ 10, 10 ], [ 20, 10 ], [ 20, 20 ], [ 10, 20 ], [ 10, 10 ] ] ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an [open issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8310#issuecomment-430287656) on github for `Sequelize` version 6.  You could try what `Americas` suggests on `GitHub`, i.e.

```
await queryInterface.bulkInsert(
    'p_zones',
    data,
    {},
    { points: { type: Sequelize.GEOMETRY('POLYGON') } });
```

Although I must admit, when I executed the above against a `postgres` database, I got the following error:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "p_zones" ("points") VALUES (GeomFromText('POLYGON((10 10,20 10,20 20,10 20,10 10))'));
(node:18964) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: function geomfromtext(unknown) does not exist
    at Query.formatError ...
```

But hopefully that's just an error due to the particular version of `PostGIS` that I have.

As an aside, your insert works fine if it's a `.bulkCreate` statement rather than a `.bulkInsert` one.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to execute a `.bulkInsert` without defining the entire model first.  Things you could try:

1. Construct a [raw query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51958893/332988) and do the bulk insert that way.
2. Try defining the model by accessing the `sequelize` object from `queryInterface.sequelize`, and then do a `.bulkCreate`, which shouldn't give you any errors.